# read.csv changes characters when importing data

Tags: r

`read.csv` changes "≥" character to a weird set of characters when importing the CSV data.

The vectors are characters (not numbers or factors).
For example, the variables for column "x" are "A≥5", "B 2-5", "C≤2"

```
read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   head(df$x)
```

```
#[1] "A â‰¥ 5"    "B 2-5"     "C â‰¥ 2"
```

Comment: What encoding was used on your input file? What command exactly did you use to read it in? What operating system are you on? This is very likely just an encoding issue.

Comment: I used read.csv
I'm using RStudio 1.1.463 on Windows 10

Comment: @MrFlick I edited the  question

Comment: That still doesn't answer any of the encoding questions. How was your input file created? What encoding was used? Was it UTF-8, was it Latin-1, was it come other code page? Clues about that would come from what operating system was used to create the file and where you are trying to read the file.

Comment: @MrFlick OK. I added "encoding = UTF-8" and it solved the problem! Thanks so much.

Comment: given the output it looks like conversion from UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the comments. I changed the code to:

```
read.csv("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

This solved my problem.